# Define Data Type c# in Parse Using rest API

Tags: c#, json, api, rest, parse-platform

I'm using parse rest api, I can't define the data type when I try to add new column. I read through the api document but have no idea how to declare the value type

```
Example : {
  "__type": "Date",
  "iso": "2011-08-21T18:02:52.249Z"
}
```

Below is my code. I try to declare "andScheduleMode" field to boolean and insert boolean value, but somehow it return 400 bad request, invalid json

#### Schedule Task #Test 1 (it success, but it column become string type.)

```
public void parseUpdateWidthHeightScheduleMode()
{
  String queryUpdateString = queryUrl + this.objectId;
  string data = "{\"Width\": \"" + Width + "\",\"Height\": \"" + Height + "\",\"andScheduleMode\": \"" + andScheduleMode + "\"}";
  Parse.update(queryUpdateString, data);
}
```

#### Schedule Task #Test 2 (it return invalid json)

```
public void parseUpdateWidthHeightScheduleMode()
{
  String queryUpdateString = queryUrl + this.objectId;
  string data = "{\"Width\": \"" + Width + "\",\"Height\": \"" + Height + "\",\"andScheduleMode\":" + andScheduleMode + "}";
  Parse.update(queryUpdateString, data);
}
```

#### namespace Parse

```
public static DateTime update(String url, String data)
{
  WebRequest webRequest = ParseWebRequest(url, "PUT", "application/json", true);

  byte[] dataStream = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
  webRequest.ContentLength = dataStream.Length;

  Stream newStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();


   // Send the data.
   newStream.Write(dataStream, 0, dataStream.Length);
   newStream.Close();


   WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
   Stream objStream = webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
   StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(objStream);
   String objJSON = objReader.ReadToEnd();
   dynamic JsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(objJSON);

   DateTime updatedAt = Convert.ToDateTime(JsonData.updatedAt);
   return updatedAt;
 }
```

Comment: Log the JSON you're generating in each test

Comment: Hi Wain, the json should be correct. The problem now is don't know how to declare boolean / number type in c#. I try few cases using number fields. I created on parse dashboard, and assign the value without double quotes, is work fine. Then I delete again the column, and using the code to create the number type column, it become string column, and it said my codes is invalid json. (the reason is no double quotes)